# Adjust horizontal space between vertical TiKz-chains the elegant way

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

The example below work and looks ok.
But I think about if there is a more elegant/generic/tikz way to manipulate the space between different chains.

*Elegant* here means, that it would be nice to specify the space between chains in a relative way. In this example I use explicite fixed values `2cm`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [start chain=A going below,
     start chain=B going below,
     every node/.style=draw]

    \node at (0,0) {One};

    \node [on chain=A,right=2cm] at (1,0) {Two};
    \node [on chain=A] {\ldots};

    \node [on chain=B,right=4cm] at (2,0) {Three};
    \node [on chain=B] {\ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not really clear what you mean by a 'more elegant/generic/TikZ' approach here. Obviously, your code is TikZ.

It is recommended to use the `positioning` library rather than the older syntax, but I would probably just stick to using chains:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    start chain=main going right,
    every node/.style=draw
  ]

  \node [on chain] {One};
  \node [on chain] {Two};
  {[start branch=A going below]
    \node [on chain] {\ldots};
  }
  \node [on chain] {Three};
  {[start branch=B going below]
    \node [on chain] {\ldots};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: branched chain]

Comment: nested chains? nice.

Comment: How would you use `positioning` here?

Comment: btw: Line 6 and 7 could be deleted. Correct? My code works without them.

Comment: Oops. Yes, absolutely you don't need those. I just forgot to remove them. You can use `positioning` but the whole idea of chains is really that you don't have to specify explicitly where things are in relation to others but just the general direction.