# adjust branch distance equally by borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289095/70324) SO, I try below example but the distance between branches is calculated center by center now. how can I improve it to put 3 branches equally distributed border by border?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        node distance=0 and 2cm,
        start chain=going right,
        box/.style={on chain,draw,outer sep=0,inner sep=2pt},
        hide/.style={on chain,draw=none,inner sep=0},
    }

\node[hide]  {};
\begin{scope}[start branch=B1 going below]
    \foreach \x in {A,B,C,D} {
    \node[box,text width=2cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}

\node[hide] {};
\begin{scope}[start branch=B2 going below]
    \foreach \x in {E,F,G,H,I,J,K} {
    \node[box,text width=1cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}

\node[hide] {};
\begin{scope}[start branch=B3 going below]
\foreach \x in {L,M,N} {
    \node[box,text width=1cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any `hide` nodes or other tricks, just a `matrix`, the distance can be adjusted via `column sep`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        node distance=0 and 2cm,
        box/.style={on chain,draw,outer sep=0,inner sep=2pt},
    }
\matrix[column sep=3em]{
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below]
    \foreach \x in {A,B,C,D} {
    \node[box,text width=2cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}
&
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below]
    \foreach \x in {E,F,G,H,I,J,K} {
    \node[box,text width=1cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}
& 
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below]
\foreach \x in {L,M,N} {
    \node[box,text width=1cm] (\x) {\x};
}
\end{scope}
\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]